# Bind column to data javafx

Tags: javafx, tableview, bind, multiple-columns

Let me first explain what I did.

1. I am having list of tables in the drop down
2. when someone select any one it will populate all the data to tableview with respect to column name

I am able to get the columns from the table and put it in the tableview but I am not able to bind the data with associated columns.

My code here is to look

```
        this.tableName  =   clsComboData.getValue();

    System.out.println(tableName); System.out.println("Button Pressed");
    List<StaticColumnConfig> allColumns =   null;
    for(StaticDataTable dataTable : dropdown) {
        if(dataTable.getTableName() != null && dataTable.getTableName().equalsIgnoreCase(tableName)) {
            System.out.println(dataTable.getColumnConfig());
            allColumns  =   dataTable.getColumnConfig();
         }
    }

    switch (tableName) {
    case "IOSwapCounterparties":    SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("2015-04-15");
                                    System.out.println("Into the Switch");
                                    data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                                        new IOSwapCounterparties(1,"a","b","c","d","e",date),
                                        new IOSwapCounterparties(1,"aa","bb","cv","dd","es",date),
                                        new IOSwapCounterparties(1,"ad","bd","cd","dc","eb",date),
                                        new IOSwapCounterparties(1,"aw","bw","cr","dt","ey",date),
                                        new IOSwapCounterparties(1,"ag","bt","cy","du","ep",date)
                                    );
             break;
    }

    //System.out.println("Its in ELSE");            
    //"Invited" column
    TableColumn checkboxCol = new TableColumn<Person, Boolean>();

    checkboxCol.setText("");

    checkboxCol.setMinWidth(50);

    checkboxCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("checkbox"));
    // Create checkboxes
    checkboxCol.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Person, Boolean>, TableCell<Person, Boolean>>() {
        public TableCell<Person, Boolean> call(TableColumn<Person, Boolean> p) {

            CheckBoxTableCell<Person, Boolean> checkBox = new CheckBoxTableCell();              
            return checkBox;

        }
    });         

    //Set cell factory for cells that allow editing
    Callback<TableColumn, TableCell> cellFactory =
      new Callback<TableColumn, TableCell>() {
        public TableCell call(TableColumn p) {

            return new EditingCell();

        }
    };

    for(StaticColumnConfig column : allColumns){                                
        TableColumn oneColumn = new TableColumn(column.getColumnName());
        oneColumn.setCellFactory(cellFactory);
    }

    // Clear the tableview for next table
    tblViewer.getColumns().clear();     
    // Push the data to the tableview
    tblViewer.setItems(data);           
    tblViewer.setEditable(true);

    tblViewer.getColumns().addAll(checkboxCol);
    for(StaticColumnConfig column : allColumns){
        System.out.println(column.getColumnName());

        TableColumn oneColumn = new TableColumn(column.getColumnName());
        tblViewer.getColumns().addAll(oneColumn);

    }

    // Add the columns
    tblViewer.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);             
    tblViewer.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
```

Comment: I figured out the solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is been uppercase - lowercase mistake with my getter and setter method.